# Was Casablanca a "safe" place for the Allies to hold a global conference in January, 1943?

Tags: world-war-two, diplomacy, north-africa, morocco

In January 1943, America's President Roosevelt and Britain's Winston Churchill held a conference in [Casablanca, Morocco.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casablanca_Conference) Russia's Stalin declined to attend (citing the fighting at Stalingrad). One "real" reason may be that there was no totally safe, clear, path from Moscow to Morocco. (Stalin attended a later conference in Tehran, Iran, in November 1943, with the two others, at a place and time that was probably safer than Casablanca in January, 1943.)

This was at a time when there was a German army (and air force) at large in Tunisia, and German submarines were operating through most of the Atlantic Ocean (although their level of activity around North Africa was unexpectedly low). In February, 1943, the Germans under Rommel launched a counterattack through Kasesrine Pass, which, had it succeeded, might have driven the Anglo-American armies back across Algeria, toward Morocco.

Was it possible, under the circumstances, for the Allied armies, fleet and air force to "guarantee" the safety of the two world leaders? Or did Roosevelt and Churchill deliberately hold a conference in a "dangerous" place to (quite literally) "rally the troops?"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Casablanca is further from Tunis than London is from Berlin. Would you have regarded London in January 1943 as *safe enough*?
2. The *Vichy French* had switched sides easily enough a two months earlier, so there was no realistic sense of domestic trouble in Casablanca, or French NW Africa.
3. The premise that that German attack at the Kasserine Pass might have thrown the Allies out of NW Africa falls under the realm of *alternative history*; wasn't happening no-how, no-way. It caught completely green American recruits, under trained and under poor leadership, by surprise, and **succeeded** to a much greater extent than it truly had any right to.
4. Churchill regularly proved his bravery during the Blitz, wandering around London at all hours of the day or night; he might easily have engaged in a caper such as you suggest. My belief is that Stalin, and Roosevelt at least through the 1944 election, regarded themselves as *indispensable*, and would thus not have put themselves in personal jeopardy.

With the battle for Stalingrad still underway, one can easily imagine Stalin's potential difficulties in getting to Casablanca. Any further East might similarly be problematic for Churchill and Roosevelt at that point in time.

Also, the troops needed no *rallying* by January 1943. The writing is already on the wall with Paulus surrounded in Stalingrad, and Rommel/Kesselring *for all intents and purposes* already thrown out of North Africa. Midway has already broken the Japanese navy. (Only Hirohito's war council could *lose the war in an afternoon*, as they did by rolling the dice so emphatically with that battle.)

**[Update](http://www.freemaptools.com/how-far-is-it-between-berlin_-germany-and-london_-uk.htm)**:

```
London to Berlin:     580 miles ( 932 km)
Casablanca to Tunis: 1027 miles (1653 km)
Alexandria to Tunis: 1194 miles (1922 km)
```

**Update #2**:
While the [Henkel 111](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinkel_He_111) had the range (1800 km) to fly a mission to Casablanca from Tunis, it's cruising speed of 310 km would have meant surviving 5 hours of attack by Allied fighters to arrive over the target. As a level bomber it would have had to flatten an area probably of a square mile or so in order to have a realistic chance of eliminating the assembled leaders, even assuming they failed to relocate within the city. That latter means getting one or two bombers through is most likely insufficient to achieve the goal, most of the wing would have to get through for a good probability of success.

---

**Update - re *safety* of Stalin flying from Moscow to Casablanca and back**

In **Hinge of Fate**, Churchill records his itinerary from Gibraltar to Moscow in August 1942 as:

*Gibraltar -> Cairo (over the Spanish and Vichy territories for about the first 4 hours in daylight and with an armed escort, undisturbed though nerve-wracking!) -> Tehran -> Kuibyshev -> Moscow. However the planned stop-over at Kuibyshev was skipped (to WST's regret at missing an expected feast) as weather was favourable and time urgent.*

FDR writes (ibid p 668) to Churchill:

> My route [to Casablanca] would be either from here to Trinidad and thence to Dakar and thence north, or from here to Natal (Brazil) and across to Liberia or Freetown, and north from there.

Comment: London is "closer" to Berlin than Casablanca to Tunis as the crow flies. But guarded by a large anti-tank ditch aka the English Channel.

Comment: I think the Mediterranean counts as fair anti-tank ditch also. Kesselring was making surprise tank attacks on Casablanca from Tunis with the same likelihood of making surprise tank attacks on Alexandria (see update of comparative distances above).

Comment: I completely agree with this answer. From November 1942 to the final collapse in May 1943, the Axis was constantly *defending*, and had absolutely no offensive capabilities outside the boundaries of Tunisia, let alone the center of Morocco.

Comment: Worth noting that the distance from Tunis to Casablanca (1652 km) is roughly that from Baltimore to Kansas City (1706 km).

Comment: I think the real difficulty is not about the germans bombing Casablanca from Tunis. It is about how would Uncle Joe travel. It was possible to fly UK->Africa and USA->Brazil->Africa. Not sure if they could also land in Açores in 1943. And heavy escorts could minimize the sub danger in the Atlantic. But could Uncle Joe fly USSR->UK via Norway? Or USSR->Africa via Middle East? Would a long detour via Iran, or South Africa be needed to avoid flying directly over tunisia? Could Stalin come by ship via Norway? How long would a safe option take? So may be his questions makes sense.

Comment: I recall reading that Stalin was deathly afraid of flying. I believe he tried it only once and hated every second. I've seen claims that this is why the Tehran and Yalta conferences were held where they were; Stalin could travel overland. I've read a lot of books on Stalin; I don't recall which ones made these assertions.

Comment: @Henry: Winston CHurchill (**Hinge of Fate**, page 663) writes in his letter of 26 Nov. 42 to FDR: "*[Stalin] talked with some zest of his desire to fly [to a conference with WSC and FDR] and of his confidence in the Russian machines.*" That is a first hand account, and cannot be dispensed with by mere hearsay. Do you have a solid reference?

Comment: @Luiz: In **Hinge of Fate**, Churchill discusses (pp 661-665) how initial plans for an early 1943 summit first consider Reykjavik and Khartoum before settling on a location in North Africa, initally supposed to be Marakech. In a letter to Stalin of 3 Dec. 42 he writes: "*.... [North Africa] is far better than the Iceland project we talked of in Moscow. You could get to any point desired in three days, I on two, and the President in a bout the same time as you. ....*" 1/2

Comment: @Luiz: FDR later writes (p 668): "*My route [to Casablanca] would be either from here to Trinidad and thence to Dakar and thence north, or from here to Natal (Brazil) and across to Liberia or Freetown, and north from there.*" 2/2

Comment: Pieter, nice reference! FDR traveling USA->(Caribbean/Brazil)->Africa is clear. About Stalin, do you have an idea about which exact route USSR->Africa Churchill had in mind? This is the interesting point. Norway? Iran? Or Siberia->USA, as Japan was neutral regarding the USSR?

Comment: @Luiz: From **Hinge of Fate** again: WST's planned route to Moscow in Aug. '42 was Gibraltar -> Cairo (over the Spanish and Vichy territories, with an armed escort, in daylight!) -> Tehran -> Kuibyshev -> Moscow. However the planned stop-over at Kuibyshev was skipped (to WST's regret at missing an expected feast) as weather was favourable and time urgent.

Comment: Great, I think you should update the answer. It is clear by the new reference that Churchill believed that flying over Africa was possible even if the Axis was in Tunisia. With armed escort, nonetheless!

Comment: For information on Stalin's fear of flying, see Despots Aloft https://www.airspacemag.com/history-of-flight/despots-aloft-8139864/?page=5 The article claims Stalin only flew once in his life (to the Tehran Conference in 1943) and hid his fear of flying "behind a facade of air enthusiasm". He preferred to travel by motorcade, or an armored train for longer distances. He only agreed to fly to Tehran because no secure rail route was available.